# How to get cover pictue link of an google plus profile using this method?

Tags: php, google-oauth

I am recently following a tutorial that How to authenticate with google

They use this method to pull the data

```
 echo '<div class="welcome_txt">Welcome <b>'.$_SESSION['google_data']['given_name'].'</b></div>';
echo '<div class="google_box">';
echo '<p class="image"><img src="'.$_SESSION['google_data']['picture'].'" alt="" width="300" height="220"/></p>';
echo '<p><b>Google ID : </b>' . $_SESSION['google_data']['id'].'</p>';
echo '<p><b>Name : </b>' . $_SESSION['google_data']['name'].'</p>';
echo '<p><b>Email : </b>' . $_SESSION['google_data']['email'].'</p>';
echo '<p><b>Gender : </b>' . $_SESSION['google_data']['gender'].'</p>';
echo '<p><b>Locale : </b>' . $_SESSION['google_data']['locale'].'</p>';
echo '<p><b>Google+ Link : </b>' . $_SESSION['google_data']['link'].'</p>'
```

By using this method How to pull the cover pic ..Help me

index.php

```
<?php 

include_once("config.php");
include_once("includes/functions.php");

//print_r($_GET);die;

if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
  $gClient->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
  $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
  //DB Insert
  $gUser = new Users();
  $gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture']);
  $_SESSION['google_data'] = $userProfile; // Storing Google User Data in Session
  header("location: feed.php");
  $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}

?>
```

Comment: ^ That method is not complete. How can we answer you without knowing how you are getting the `$_SESSION['google_data']`? Please think twice on how developers understand, does the question contain the full information.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience I made.I jus added index.php @PraveenKumar